# List disappears when PullRefresh plugin in Sencha Touch 2.2

Tags: javascript, list, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I added the pullRefresh plugin to my list and the list doesn't display anymore. No errors or warnings in the console. Is there sth I should do when I add a plugin?

```
    {   xtype:'list',
    itemId:'boxes',
    scrollable:true,
    disableSelection:true,
    plugins: [
        {   xclass: 'Ext.plugin.PullRefresh',
            pullRefreshText: '...',
            refreshFn: function(plugin) {
                console.log('I am pulled');
            }
        }
    ],
    listeners:{
        itemtap:function(){
            ...;
        } 
    },
    height:'100%',
    grouped:true,
    store:{
        grouper: {
            groupFn: function(record) {
                ...
            }
        },
        fields:[...],
        data:[]
    },
    itemTpl:'...'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When plugging the pullRefresh the list width must be specified in order to display properly. I added `width:'100%'` and it worked fine.